# NHibernate Paged Results & Incorrect Row Count

Tags: .net, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, icriteria

I have a model called 'BusinessPage' which can be associated with 1 or more 'BusinessPageCategories'. So I've got a 3rd table called 'BusinessPagesInCategories' that links these two.

I am trying to get a paged recordset of BusinessPages, along with the total number of records (I may have 100 rows in total but only return 20 at a time, but I pass back an int containing that total number in addition to the 20 rows).

The problem I have is that, since I implemented the Many-To-Many relationship, it was bringing back the same BusinessPage row x times (where x is the number of categories that BusinessPage is associated with). I only want a single instance of each business page to be returned. So I added the following to my NHibernate Criteria to give Distinct BusinessPage results.

```
.SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity);
```

Whilst this works for me, in that I'm now correctly getting a single row per BusinessPage (and my Categories property within each BusinessPage contains the correct x categories that it's assigned to), my row count is *not* reflecting that 'distinct' count - instead, if I have just 1 BusinessPage record which is associated with 3 categories, the row count is 3!?!

**BusinessPage (Model)**

```
public virtual int BusinessPageId { get; private set; }
public virtual IList<BusinessPageCategory> Categories { get; set; }
public virtual string BusinessName { get; set; }
```

**BusinessPageCategory (Model)**

```
public virtual int CategoryId { get; private set; }
public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
```

**BusinessPagesInCategories (SQL Table used to relate the two models)**

```
BusinessPageId
CategoryId
```

Here is the code I use to get my 'paged business pages':

```
public virtual IList<BusinessPage> GetPagedBusinessPages(int pageNumber, int pageSize, out int totalRecordCount)
{
    ICriteria c = CreateCriteria_BusinessPage()

        // we only want distinct business pages returned
        .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity);

    return c.PagedResults<BusinessPage>(pageNumber, pageSize, out totalRecordCount);
}

protected virtual ICriteria CreateCriteria_BusinessPage()
{
    return Session
        .CreateCriteria<BusinessPage>()
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc("BusinessName"));
}
```

And here are my extension methods for getting both the paged results AND the all important row count.

```
public static IList<T> PagedResults<T>(this ICriteria criteria, int pageNumber, int pageSize, out int totalRecordCount)
{
    var results = criteria
        .CloneNewCriteria()
        .SetPaging(pageNumber, pageSize)
        .Future<T>();

        totalRecordCount = criteria.GetTotalCount().Value;

        return results.ToList<T>();
}

public static ICriteria CloneNewCriteria(this ICriteria criteria)
{
    return CriteriaTransformer.Clone(criteria);
}

public static ICriteria SetPaging(this ICriteria criteria, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    return criteria
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
        .SetFirstResult((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize);
}

public static IFutureValue<int> GetTotalCount(this ICriteria criteria)
{
    criteria.ClearOrders();

    return criteria
        .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())
        .FutureValue<int>();
}
```

I'm still very new to NHibernate so there may be a simple solution to this?

Comment: Remember that no matter how sophisticated NHibernate is (or any other ORM for that matter), there's *still always a relational database and SQL* underneath the ORM. Everything you have learned about relational databases still applies when using an ORM. Think about it in relational terms and you'll understand the reason for this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still very new to NHibernate / ORM's in general, so how to go about using NHibernate in a way that resolves this issue remains a problem that I'm properly stuck on :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It turns out that I was setting up an Alias to the Categories regardless of whether I need to filter by category or not, therefore, the join was established in a scenario I didn't need it to be, and as a result was bringing back the duplicate rows (one for each join onto the categories)!

In the scenario whereby I do need to pass in a categoryid and filter my results on that category, there are no duplicate rows via the joins as each businesspage can be assigned any 1 category just the once.

I thought it was strange that it was making this join to categories even though I wasn't wanting to reference the categories object until after I had the initial records returned, but it looks like creating that alias outside of the scope required, forced the join and the loading of those categories unnecessarily.